# can we do UNDO from Google app script for spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Actually I am trying to catch a changes using onChange event in Google spreadsheet using google app script. I am looking for do the UNDO which is exactly what we do in UI. The reason behind is I would like to control the add/remove column.

Please help me on this.

Comment: It is possible to detect a column being deleted with an "On Change" event.  There is a `REMOVE_COLUMN` value of the `changeType` property in the event object.  [Apps Script event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)  But I don't know of a "built-in" way to undo the deletion of a column with Apps Script.  I'd be interested if someone has a way to do this, but I can't think of how it would be done.